# How do I match seasons/episodes against a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, match

I need to find out if a variable includes `S00E00` when the numbers are unknown. I have tried a lot of different things and I can identify both the letters and numbers, but only separately. Basically what I need is to identify whether a file is a tv-show or not from standard naming as defined here: https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200220687-Naming-Series-Season-Based-TV-Shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
/
  \b    # word boundary
   s    # letter s
  \d{2} # exactly 2 digits
   e    # letter e
  \d{2} # exactly 2 digits
  \b    # word boundary
/ix     # case- and space-insensitive matching
```

For example:

```
str = 'Heroes - s01e02 - The Coming Storm.avi'
str.match /\bs\d{2}e\d{2}\b/i
#=> #<MatchData "s01e02">
```

Comment: +1 For breaking up the regular expression and explaining each component.